# DeepEqual incorrect after serializing map into gob

Tags: go, reflection, slice, gob

I've encountered some strange behavior with reflect.DeepEqual. I have an object of type `map[string][]string`, with one key whose value is an empty slice. When I use gob to encode this object, and then decode it into another map, these two maps are not equal according to reflect.DeepEqual (even though the content is identical).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    m0 := make(map[string][]string)
    m0["apple"] = []string{}

    // Encode m0 to bytes
    var network bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&network)
    enc.Encode(m0)

    // Decode bytes into a new map m2
    dec := gob.NewDecoder(&network)
    m2 := make(map[string][]string)
    dec.Decode(&m2)

    fmt.Printf("%t\n", reflect.DeepEqual(m0, m2)) // false
    fmt.Printf("m0: %+v != m2: %+v\n", m0, m2) // they look equal to me!
}
```

Output:

```
false
m0: map[apple:[]] != m2: map[apple:[]]
```

A couple notes from follow-up experiments:

If I make the value of `m0["apple"]` a nonempty slice, for example `m0["apple"] = []string{"pear"}`, then DeepEqual returns true.

If I keep the value as an empty slice but I construct the identical map from scratch rather than with gob, then DeepEqual returns true:

```
m1 := make(map[string][]string)
m1["apple"] = []string{}
fmt.Printf("%t\n", reflect.DeepEqual(m0, m1)) // true!
```

So it's not strictly an issue with how DeepEqual handles empty slices; it's some strange interaction between that and gob's serialization.

Comment: Guessing it's something to do with a `nil` slice and an empty slice being treated the same in most places, but possibly not within `DeepEqual`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you encode an empty slice, and during decoding the [`encoding/gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package only allocates a slice if the one provided (the target to decode into) is not big enough to accomodate the encoded values. This is documented at: [gob: Types and Values:](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#hdr-Types_and_Values)

> In general, if allocation is required, the decoder will allocate memory. If not, it will update the destination variables with values read from the stream.

Since there are 0 elements encoded, and a `nil` slice is perfectly capable of accomodating 0 elements, no slice will be allocated. We can verify this if we print the result of comparing the slices to `nil`:

```
fmt.Println(m0["apple"] == nil, m2["apple"] == nil)
```

Output of the above is (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jUf2gN_l5rU)):

```
true false
```

Note that the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package prints `nil` slice values and empty slices the same way: as `[]`, you cannot rely on its output to judge if a slices is `nil` or not.

And [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) treats a `nil` slice and an empty but non-`nil` slice different (non-deep equal):

> Note that a non-nil empty slice and a nil slice (for example, []byte{} and []byte(nil)) are not deeply equal.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So the main problem is that gob treats nil slices and empty slices the same, but DeepEqual does not. Do you think there is a good reason for this, or should one of the packages be changed? Wondering if I should submit a git issue

Comment: @rampatowl `gob` does not treat `nil` and empty slices the same, but it does not allocate a slice if the "existing" one is enough to hold the encoded elements. If this is an issue for you, use `nil` slices in place of empty ones before encoding. I don't think these are flawed. `gob` does so to minimize allocations (and therefore improve performance).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I'm surprised that the encoding works when a map value is `nil`, because in the case where the value type is a pointer, this gives me a `gob: encodeReflectValue: nil element` error. In case you have any insights about this contradiction, I posted a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725102/gob-cant-encode-map-with-a-nil-pointer-value